# Teredo Tunneling Adapter is Non-Existant

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, adapter, teredo

So, I've been having some problems recently with my teredo adapter and I wasn't sure what was wrong. Until I looked in device manager and noticed it wasn't there. And yes, even with hidden devices shown. So, I thought it got uninstalled somehow, all I have to do is "Add legacy hardware" and reinstall it. However, it wasn't under the list of microsoft devices no matter what I did or where I went. So I looked for fixes. I've changed the disabled components in the registry to 0 as well as navigated to the TcpIp6 section and made sure everything was in line. All of this was done and I can't find any other fixes or anything and I'm feeling like I can't solve it. Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Please add an OS tag. You'll probably have to restart/enable whatever component in your OS provides the teredo adapter.

Comment: My bad, it's Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it's now fixed. It was hamachi. I uninstalled it.